# Why do I get a UserCodeSyntaxError when I have no syntax error in my code?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm currently creating a Dialogflow chatbot in nodejs and upon deploying my code I get an error message. I've attempted to uncomment most things out to just be left with the base functioning code and I am still unable to get it working. I'm not exactly sure what the issue is here

```
'use strict';
  import {getAPIresponse} from "./api/index.js";

// const http = require('https');

// const respond = fulfillmentText => {
//   return {
//     statusCode: 200,
//     body: JSON.stringify({
//       fulfillmentText
//     }),
//     headers: {
//       "Content-Type": "application/json"
//     }
//   }
//
// };

module.exports.dining = async (event,context) => {


    const incoming= JSON.parse(event.body).queryResult;

    console.log(`INCOMING: ${incoming.parameters.hall}`);

    const {
      displayName
    } = incoming.intent;

    console.log(displayName);


    //const menu = getAPIresponse('https://esb.prod.uds.harvard.edu/api/dining/2.0/','events?locationId=36');
    //console.log(menu);
    // if(displayName === 'dining'){
    //   if(incoming.parameters.meal === 'breakfast'){
    //     //get's dining hall code to include in API request
    //     const hall = getCode(incoming.parameters.hall);
    //     //generate response from API based off of parameters passed by user
    //     const menu = getAPIresponse("https://esb.prod.uds.harvard.edu/api/dining/2.0/","events?locationId=${hall}", hall);
    //     console.log(menu);
    //   }
    //   if(incoming.parameters.meal === 'lunch'){
    //     //get's dining hall code to include in API request
    //     const hall = getCode(incoming.parameters.hall);
    //     //generate response from API based off of parameters passed by user
    //     const menu = getAPIresponse("https://esb.prod.uds.harvard.edu/api/dining/2.0","/events", hall);
    //   }
    //   if(incoming.parameters.meal === 'dinner'){
    //     //get's dining hall code to include in API request
    //     const hall = getCode(incoming.parameters.hall);
    //     //generate response from API based off of parameters passed by user
    //     const menu = getAPIresponse("https://esb.prod.uds.harvard.edu/api/dining/2.0","/events", hall);
    //   }
    // }
};
```

Almost everything is commented out and I still get the error message that reads

```
2019-07-02 16:31:33.351 (-04:00)        undefined       ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {
"errorType":"Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError","errorMessage":"SyntaxError: Unexpected tok
en {","stack":["Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {","    at
 _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:98:13)","    at Object.module.exports.loa
d (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/ind
ex.js:36:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)","    a
t Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)","    at Modu
le.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)","    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modu
les/cjs/loader.js:539:12)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader
.js:531:3)","    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)",
"    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"]}
```

Comment: Are you sure the syntax error is not in `./api/index.js`?

Comment: what a horrifically unhelpful trace

Comment: Alley, they are all useless

Answer (score 24, accepted):

AWS Lambda does not support the ES6 `import` specifier as you've written here

```
import {getAPIresponse} from "./api/index.js";
```

because the ES6 `import` syntax isn't yet supported by default in Node.js (note: my lambda runtime was set to Node.js 10.x).

**Illustration:**

I was having this issue as well when importing a library at the top of my lambda distribution's `index.js` file.

The stacktrace `Uncaught Exception  { "errorType":"Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError", ... unexpected token import found ... blabla... } ...` was thrown in my lambda function when I used the `import` syntax:

```
import awsServerlessExpress from 'aws-serverless-express';

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  console.log('hello world!')
};
```

But not in this version below when I just used the standard module `require` syntax.

```
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  console.log('hello world!')
};
```

For me, it was the `import` syntax that was causing the `SyntaxError` exceptions, but do take note that, for you, any JavaScript syntax not supported by your current Node.js runtime will throw this exception.

**A couple of solutions:**

1. Change all `import` statements to standard module `require` statements and keep using whatever default JavaScript flavour is supported by your configured Node.js runtime.
2. Use a transpiler like Babel w/ Webpack to transpile your ES6 JavaScript before deploying to the cloud.
3. Use the quick solution nicely described by Yitzchak below :) Just bump the NodeJS version on your Lambda Dashboard.

Answer (score 47):

### Worked for me: Updating Node.js version of lambda

I got this error because lambda was defined to execute with **Node.js 12.x**, when I changed it to **Node.js 14.x** (as on my local machine) it worked

[image]

If it works - and you're generally using the **serverless** package to automate the deployment of your lambda - don't forget to update your **serverless.yml** file accordingly

[image: serverless.yml change runtime: nodejs14.x]

Comment: Thank you, saved my day... Any ideas why did this happen? In my case, it was working just fine before.

Comment: @julioMilani happened to me because I’ve changed some code. Used the ‘??’ Operator if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I pasted code from another lambda which had node version 14.
But my current lambda node version was 12.
The code I pasted was using optional chaining(?.) in one line. Removed it, deployed code and it worked fine.

Comment: This saved one of my coding lives, thanks! On to the next level lol. (optional chaining almost did me in)

Comment: In my case it was safe to bump the runtime from 12 to 16

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes in lambda, when we click on `Deploy` all the changes are not deployed. Refresh the page and check for syntax errors.
or at least that's what was the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TypeScript and encounter this error make sure the target you set in `tsconfig.json` matches your targeted nodejs version. For a list of recommended settings visit [Node Target Mapping](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Node-Target-Mapping)

For example I was targeting node.js 12 and using `ES2020`. Changing this to `ES2019` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed the `tsconfig.json` `module` setting:

```json
"module": "es2015"
```

to

```json
"module": "CommonJS",
```

ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module

Answer (score 0):

I have seen these errors happening when there is a runtime failure

Such as I have written an if/else block without end braces. So please make sure that your code is "compiling" properly

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the issue was caused by having ";" within the blocks in my code below, so pretty much as the error described - `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'"`.

```
const putReqs = batch.map(item => ({
        PutRequest: {
            Item: item;
        }
    }))

    const req = {
        RequestItems: {
            tmp-customer-address: putReqs;
        }
    }
```

Once I moved the ";" outside the code blocks, it fixed the problem.

```
const putReqs = batch.map(item => ({
        PutRequest: {
            Item: item
        }
    }));

    const req = {
        RequestItems: {
            'tmp-customer-address': putReqs
        }
    };
```