# AWS Lambda fails when I import an image. Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

#### Context

I am working on a Lambda function in my `index.js` file to help me add watermark on images using Sharp.

This is the error I am getting.

```
2022-04-01T20:33:49.269Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError","errorMessage":"SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token","stack":["Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token","   
   at _loadUserApp ._loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:200:13 undefined)","   
   at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:242:17 undefined)","   
   at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30 undefined)","   
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14 undefined)","   
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10 undefined)","   
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32 undefined)","   
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12 undefined)","   
   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12 undefined)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
```

#### The Culprit

I realized the issue was happening when I imported a `.png` file.

```js
const sharp = require('sharp');
const { S3 } = require('aws-sdk');
const stream = require('stream');
const playButtonPng = require('./assets/playButton.png'); // When this is commented out, the Lambda works
```

I thought about maybe "pulling" this image from S3, but it becomes complex since Sharp requires a "real image."

So my question is: **is it possible to import a local `.png` in a lambda function?** I tried investigating but did not find any results.

#### Other Things I've tried:

- Using CommonJS imports
- Configuring Lambda to use Node `14.x` as I am using `v14.18.3` locally
- Double checking syntax. Using Babel to compile.
- Adjusting the `sharp` `node_module` for production. (I don't think this was ever the issue).

I've also looked at these threads, which suggested

- [Why do I get a UserCodeSyntaxError when I have no syntax error in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859727/why-do-i-get-a-usercodesyntaxerror-when-i-have-no-syntax-error-in-my-code)
- https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3361

Comment: Yes, you can bundle a PNG or other assets when packaging a Lambda function. You're not going to be able to `require` that file, however, because it's a PNG, not a Node.js module. Just use regular file access. BTW it's unusual to see a Lambda function hosting or serving image files. Typically you would use S3.

Answer (score 1):

load PNG file by **readFile / readFileSync** available in **fs** module.

```
var fs = require('fs')
const playButtonPng = fs.readFileSync('./assets/playButton.png')
```

Comment: Thank you! As @jarmod suggested, this is what I plan to do. `readFileSync` returns a buffer, but luckily, Sharp can support that!