# Lambda works locally, but not when deployed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I'm using serverless framework and my endpoint work locally with sls offline, but when I sls deploy it to AWS I get 502 Bad Gateway in postman
[image]

and if I go to AWS Lambda console and click test event to see what comes up I get

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:222:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:300:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:34)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
  ]
}
```

There's nothing in my code that has `??='` in it so I made my endpoint super simple as a process of elimination and returned a response instantly ie

```
router.get('/my-api', async (req, res: Response) => {
    return res.status(200).json({"message": "success"});
});
```

but I still get the same error.
serverless.yaml

```
service: my-service

plugins:
    - serverless-webpack
    - serverless-offline

custom:
    env:
        default: Sandbox
        prod: Production
        AWS_REGION: us-east-1

    apigwBinary:
        types: #list of mime-types
            - '*/*'

    contentCompression: 14000

    webpack:
        webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
        packager: 'npm'
        includeModules:
            forceExclude:
                - aws-sdk
                - dotenv

provider:
    name: aws
    versionFunctions: false
    region: ${opt:region, 'us-east-1'}
    stage: ${opt:stage, 'staging'}
    environment:
        STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
functions:
    myApi:
        handler: src/handler.service
        events:
            - http:
                  path: route/my-api
                  method: GET
                  cors: true
```

handler.ts

```
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, Context, ProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';
import awsServerlessExpress from 'aws-serverless-express';
import app from './app';

const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app);

export function service(event: APIGatewayProxyEvent, context: Context) {
    return awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
}
```

So as a recap, it works locally, but not after sls deploy in AWS in postman or aws console lambda test event. So if it works locally, why isn't it working in aws. I appreciate any help!

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3361#issuecomment-945016495

Comment: Also check your lambda node version https://stackoverflow.com/q/56859727/13126651

Comment: I believe api gateway is looking for a response such as `
```return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify('value here');``` Didn't change anything when I try this though. 
 
Also I'm on node 14. I tried putting it on node 12, but that didn't work.

Comment: Looks like a issue with the node version. Did you try updating the node version?

Comment: I thought Node 14 would be sufficient. I use it for everything locally, but I changed the version in serverless template to node 16 and deployed and it's working now. Maybe it's a package I have installed that has a version that requires > node 14. Not sure. Bu at the same time if that's the case then I would expect it to fail locally so I have no idea what's freaking out over node 14. Thanks!

Comment: If its okay I would like to post my comment as answer to this question. So that it helps others in the future

Comment: For sure. I'll accept it.